# how to refresh a particular div content when page is loading through ajax load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my html code:

```
<body onload="fun1()">
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
    <li><a href="#" id="m_blink" onclick="fun1()">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="d_blink" onclick="fun2()">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="k_blink" onclick="fun3()">Tab3</a></li>

</ul>
</body>
<div id='home'></div>
```

this the script loading the page content in a 'home' div , and if i click 'tab1' that particular 'tab1.php' loading in 'home' div and when i click 'tab2' particular tab2.php is loading in 'home' div and when i click tab3 particular  tab3.php is loading in home div,

```
 <script>
    function fun1(){

        $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
    }


    function fun2(){

            $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
    }

    function fun3(){

            $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
    }


    </script>
```

when i click on the tab1 page is loaded in home div and this home div has to refresh for every 5 seconds when tab2 page is loaded in home div and this home div has to refresh for 5 seconds and same as tab3

please check the 'onload' function is for body tag!

and i tried using setInterval(function() {});  like this :

```
function fun1(){
               setInterval(function(){
                $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
            },5000);
        }     
     function fun2(){
               setInterval(function(){
                $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
            },5000);
        }

     function fun3(){
               setInterval(function(){
                $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
            },5000);
        }
```

And the problem is when i called the page through ajax load() function than whole body of the page is loading, so i dont want to load whole page i want to refresh the page of particular div home div only, please suggest how to solve this problem.

please check onload() function i have used to call the default page tab1.php

Comment: You can specify what element `.load` will insert: `$('#home').load('tab3.php #table')`, see docs here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there have been no attempts made to write the code to do the functionality required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `.data()` method of jQuery to provide required extra info:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
    <li><a href="#" data-url="tab1.php">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-url="tab2.php">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-url="tab3.php">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you are using jQuery then better to use unobtrusive way of writing scripts like this:

```
$('#nav a').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.active').removeClass('active'); // removes the active class from other link
     $(this).addClass('active'); // adds the active class to current cliked link
     setInterval(function(){
       $("#home").load($('.active').data('url'),{},function(){}); // populates the div with data-url of active class.
     }, 5000);
});
 $('#nav li:eq(0) a').trigger('click'); // triggers the first link's click.
```

Comment: Is there any other possible way , to refresh a 'home' div when the page is loaded , without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: @John you can trigger the click like as updated in the answer.

Comment: Actually i new to php and javascript , can you please make code!

Comment: Actually, you can use the `href` attribute of the anchor as well, since it's not really being used for anything else ;-)

Comment: @Jack whoa! just didn't thought of it. that's a nice idea though.

Comment: Turned out that I've answered the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24553856/1338292); OP didn't seem to think it was a problem to post a question twice =(

Comment: @Jack true, that is really great solution but OP just didn't get that +1, ^^.

Answer (score 2):

I would organise the code like this:

```
<body>
  <ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
    <li><a href="tab1.php" id="m_blink" class="selected">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab2.php" id="d_blink">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab3.php" id="k_blink">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
<div id='home'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $current,
    timer;

    // change current tab based on given anchor
    function changeTab($element)
    {
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer); // clear old timer
        }

        $current = $element;

        // set new timer
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            refreshCurrentTab();
        }, 5000);

        // and call immediately
        refreshCurrentTab();
    }

    function refreshCurrentTab()
    {
        $('#home').load($current.prop('href'));
    }

    $('#nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        changeTab($(this));
    });

    changeTab($('#nav .selected')); // initial tab
});
```

Comment: Actually , i am new to php and javascript , can you please provide me easy code

Comment: @John Well, what you want is not entirely trivial; so this is about as simple as I can make it.

Comment: +1 for complete solution that can't be beaten in any way. Such a shame that John can't understand that...

Answer (score 0):

tr something like this

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    //adding click event
    $('#nav li a').click(function(){
        var url  =  this.id + '.php';
        $("#home").load(url,{},function(){
            // store your page id which is currently loaded with data attribute on #home element
            $("#home").data('current_page',this.id);
        });
    })

    // auto refresh function
    setInterval(function(){
        // retrieve page if which is currently loaded with data attribute on #home element
         var current_page = $("#home").data('current_page');
            var url=  current_page + '.php';
            $("#home").load(url);
    },5000);
});
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
        <li><a href="#" id="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='home' data-current_page='tab1'> </div>
</body>
```

**EDITED** [According to your code]

**javascript**

```
//default page
var page = 'tab1.php';
function fun1(){
    page = "tab1.php";
    $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
}


function fun2(){
    page = "tab2.php";
    $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
}

function fun3(){
    page = "tab3.php";
    $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
}


function autorefresh(){
       setInterval(function(){
        $("#home").load(page,{},function(){});
    },5000);
}
```

**html**

```
<body onload="autorefresh()">
    <ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
        <li><a href="#" id="m_blink" onclick="fun1()">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="d_blink" onclick="fun2()">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="k_blink" onclick="fun3()">Tab3</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id='home'></div>
```

Comment: Actually i am new to php and javascript, pleas tell me the current_page means?

Comment: And also the in body tag , onload funtion is there when the page loads default page should load.

Comment: current_page is virtual variable name that is bind with home div check this out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: Yes i have done like this , according to my code is there any other possible way , can you please share the code .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple implementation of what you've requested. Contains comments, so you should be able to follow through it.

also, you can easily update this to auto-update using `setInterval()` function:

**test.php** *single page demo*

```
<?php

// Dummy Ajax Handler
if (!empty($_GET['load']))
{
    switch ($_GET['load'])
    {
        case 'tab1':
            echo "hello from tab 1";
            break;

        case 'tab2':
            echo "hello from tab 2";
            break;

        case 'tab3':
            echo "hello from tab 3";
            break;
    }
    exit();
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When Page Loads
$(function()
{
    // Load Tab 1 By Default
    $('#home').load('test.php?load=tab1');

    // Handle Nav Clicks
    $('#nav li a').click(function()
    {
        // Load Requested Tab
        $('#home').load('test.php?load=tab' + $(this).attr('data-tab'));
    });
});

</script>


<ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
    <li><a href="#" data-tab="1" id="m_blink">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tab="2" id="d_blink">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tab="3" id="k_blink">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home"></div>
```

Comment: I have done according to your code ,the whole page is loading ,

Comment: is there any other possible way can do with my code , can you please share the code!

Answer (score 0):

In html, I removed all javascript you have there. It is not good to mix html code with javascript code, it is less understandable.

```
<body>
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
<li><a href="#" id="m_blink">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="d_blink">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="k_blink">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
<div id='home'></div>
```

in javascript:

```
// First we need to make onload, that we removed from html.
// So I make a function and bind it to window.onload, which is almost same as
// <body onload="bla()">
// Everything inside the function will then happen after html is loaded 
// in browser, which is very important, because we cant manipulate with 
// elements that doesn't exist yet.

window.onload = function() {
            // there we need to put all code
        };
```

Let's make some switch now. Do everything without refresh first. We have 3 tabs, so we need to make new content inside of home:

```
// first we need to add event onclick to our <a>
$("#m_blink").onclick(function() { });
$("#d_blink").onclick(function() { });
$("#k_blink").onclick(function() { });

// now add what should happen when you click on <a>
$("#m_blink").onclick(function() {
    $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
});

$("#d_blink").onclick(function() { 
    $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
});

$("#k_blink").onclick(function() { 
    $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
});
```

Now `setInterval` function is easy to write.

Two params, first is function you want to call, second is time in miliseconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
// do something
}, 5*1000);
```

So now first though is just do setInterval and put ajax inside, like that:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
}, 5*1000);
```

But the problem is, once user switch the tab, then after 5 seconds, interval will load data from tab1 again! How we solve the problem, easy. We will make variable `currentTable` that will hold the state which table user see. And with each table switch, we will change `currentTable`. Also we will use `currentTable` in setInterval, so function will always do what we want.

So now from scratch again, complete js code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var currentTable = "tab1.php"; // this is our initial state

    // now I define function reloadTab, because we do that all the time
    // and it is boring to write same code again and again
    function reloadTab() {
        $("#home").load(currentTable,{},function(){});
    }

    // onclicks - it is so easy now, we just change tab and call realoadTab
    $("#m_blink").onclick(function() {
        currentTable = "tab1.php";  
        reloadTab();
    });

    $("#m_blink").onclick(function() {
        currentTable = "tab2.php";  
        reloadTab();
    });

    $("#m_blink").onclick(function() {
        currentTable = "tab3.php";  
        reloadTab();
    });

    // setInterval - all we need is use reloadTab as first param
    setInterval(reloadTab, 5*1000);

}; // end of window.onload
```

So thats it, all javascript that you need is the last part.

Comment: :can you please elaborate , i dint get

Comment: Actually i am new to php and javascript , please elaborate and my question is  : when onclick on the particular HOME div has to refresh for 5 secs and tab2 is clicked the page2 content in home div has to refresh for 5 secs,

Comment: Well, now I made the code as easy as it can be. Remember, Jacks code is better, it solves problems that you can't see right now.

Comment: yes I have done with your code , its getting 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function '